# How feasible/difficult is it to run an application that runs on a router?

Tags: language-agnostic, networking, wireless, router

In my example, I want to build an application that sends users who join a network some kind of interface and manage this at a central station (possibly the router, or a central server).  The new user's input to this interface will be sent back to the central station and controlled.

How plausible is this?  Is sending something to a newly discovered IP realistic?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you control the DNS server, you can send them to any web server you like.

Comment: Unless they enter an IP address directly in the URL. (I still upvoted this idea; seems best so far.)

Answer (score 1):

Completely plausible, but you'll need a router with open source firmware and you'll need to program in the language of that source code and have the toolchain to build the binary for the firmware.

Comment: Ignacio's idea is easier. I overlooked that you're willing to use a server also that would manage incoming connections.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is [NoCatAuth](http://nocat.net/) and friends. The user has to use their web browser, but most are accustomed to that.

Comment: Incidentally, this is built-in to the open-source DD-WRT http://www.dd-wrt.com firmware that runs on various routers.

Comment: Also see OpenWRT, it has firmware that runs on a large variety of routers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to FORCE the users to use your application (e.g. by selling these routers via an ISP), or are you expecting users to co-operate (e.g. inside a organisation's WAN)?

If the latter, it may be sufficient to set the DHCP server inside the router to serve the address of an HTTP proxy. That will get picked up by most OS/browsers. The proxy can then be used to control web-traffic - which pages they can see, and which ones are redirected to your own web-app.

If the user is considered an adversary, it would be trivial for them to override the proxy settings. In a LAN/WAN situation, you need to make sure nothing is connecting them to the outside world, except through the proxy.